# React material container header main and footer it is not aligned using flexbox in the header

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My goal is to build up a simple layout

with header main and footer but I've got

problem with the alignment.

The header container is not aligned

with main and footer (is slightly shifted on the left)

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c5arn4

How can get an aligned header?

Comment: What do you mean by aligned header?

Comment: the header container is slightly shifted on the left is not aligned with the others

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, I found the reason why header container is not aligned with main and footer: is the `display: 'flex'` in `header` class that for some reason creates that padding in header.

The problem is that if you remove it, all the header will displayed like this:

[image]

So I found this solution:

keep `header` class as is and create `bck_masthead` class for header container:

```
bck_masthead: {
   backgroundColor: '#F39C6B',
   position: 'absolute',
   marginLeft: '25%'
}
```

So masthead container becomes:

```
<Container className={classes.bck_masthead} maxWidth="md">
   <div className={classes.masthead}>
      Masthead
   </div>
 </Container>
```

And the result is:

[image]

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3jeb84) your code modified.

Comment: it works but its very ugly :) thanks the same buddy

Comment: Yes, I'm not so expert in css :)